# [[Errno 2]] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp1d93dhp7.upload.mp4' in my Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I've been moving development of my website over to using Docker. I recently adjusted the location of media files when I was presented with this error:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp1d93dhp7.upload.mp4' in Django. So far I've checked for typos in my file location code in my settings, views and models.

The website works by simply storing user uploaded media files in a media folder. Uploaded files are stored in media/human.

Here is the relevant code:

views.py:

```
...
try:
            
            
            if form.is_valid() and 'file' in request.FILES:
                if not request.session.get('user_id'):
                    request.session['user_id'] = generate_unique_id()
                user_id = request.session.get('user_id')
                
                    
                print(request.session['user_id'])
                uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']

                
                
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
                uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
                file_type = mimetypes.guess_type(uploaded_file_path))

                request.session['uploaded_file_path'] = uploaded_file_path
                
                
                user_doc, created = RequirementsChat.objects.get_or_create(id=user_id)
                

            
                files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
                for file in files:
                    
                    user_doc, created = RequirementsChat.objects.get_or_create(id=user_id)
                    uploaded_file = UploadedFile(input_file=file, requirements_chat=user_doc, chat_id = user_id)
                    uploaded_file.save()
                user_doc.save()
...
```

The error seems to be caused by the `uploaded_file.save()` line.

models.py:

```
class RequirementsChat(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    transcript_file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    additional_requirements = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    task_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='human_upload/')#new
    chat_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, null= True)
    requirements_chat = models.ForeignKey(RequirementsChat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_files', null=True)
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "db1",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db", # set in docker-compose.yml
        "PORT": 5432, # default postgres port
    }
}   

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),#redirects to transcribe/,
    path('transcribe/', include('transcribe.urls')),
    path('human/', include('human.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(
settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

Dockerfile:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      -  8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      -  "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key"
      -  "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```